# What are the major lineages of Hung Gar?

Tags: southern-shaolin, hung-gar

[Hung Gar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hung_Ga) is legendary in the Chinese systems, and I'm interested in the major contemporary schools, and how much variation as arisen across them in the past 5 generations.

- What are the major lineages of Hung Gar?

Characteristics of each requested.

([Wong Fei-hung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wong_Fei-hung) is the most famous practitioner, due in part to his early mythologization in cinema.  In the early films, Lau Cham plays his teacher, Wong's disciple [Lam Sai-wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lam_Sai-wing), and Lau's son is the legendary martial director & choreographer, [Lau Kar-leung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lau_Kar-leung).  [Gordon Liu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_Liu), one of the top golden era kung fu stars is also famous for his on-screen Hung Gar, which came from the Laus.)