# What styles did Jet Li use in the "Once Upon a Time in China" films?

Tags: entertainment, choreography

I ask because [Wong Fei-hung is a legendary martial artist](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/10293/7644), portrayed by such kung fu movie stars as [Kwan Tak-hing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kwan_Tak-hing) (known to you through his nemesis in those films, [Mr. Han from Enter the Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shih_Kien#Career);)

But the most recognizable films for contemporary viewers are [Jet Li](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Li)'s *[Once Upon A Time In China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Li#Early_life_and_martial_arts_career)* films, and Li was not study [Nanquan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanquan), which includes Wong's [Hung style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hung_Ga).

- What styles did Jet Li use in [Tsui Hark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsui_Hark)'s Wong Fei-Hong films?

Comment: The character he portrayed had very wide and low stances so probably changquan. Jet li himself was also a changquan medallist. Wong fei hung founded the style hung fist and in the movie, he taught 13th aunt "kumlar" sau.

Comment: @KristinaLex I'd say longfist 100%.  He does all of the iconic longboxing movements, and it's arguably what he most excelled at.  And Jet Li wiki confirms what styles he did learn.  (Please do post a formal answer so I can accept! :) :) :)